# What is the difference between a Binding configuration and a Behavior?

Tags: .net, wcf

I'm trying to *get* WCF config files better so I can more-easily work on more-complex scenarios. As is usually the case, I'm revisiting my understanding of the basics. So this brings up the question, ***What is the difference between a Binding configuration and a Behavior?*** I'm *not* asking about what is a binding (i.e. `netTcpBinding`, etc.). I get that.

So let's say I have a config file with multiple configurations for that single binding:

```
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="LargeMessages" maxBufferPoolSize="5242880" maxBufferSize="5242880" maxReceivedMessageSize="5242880">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="256" maxStringContentLength="16384" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="None"></security>
    </binding>
    <binding name="LargeFiles" maxBufferPoolSize="15728640" maxBufferSize="15728640" maxReceivedMessageSize="15728640">
      <!-- 15MB max size -->
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="256" maxStringContentLength="15728640" maxArrayLength="15728640" maxBytesPerRead="204800" maxNameTableCharCount="15728640" />
      <security mode="None"></security>
    </binding>
    <binding name="LargeStrings" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxBufferSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="524288">
      <!-- 0.5MB max size -->
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="256" maxStringContentLength="524288" maxArrayLength="524288" maxBytesPerRead="204800" maxNameTableCharCount="524288" />
      <security mode="None"></security>
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
```

In this scenario, I'm calling `LargeMessages`, `LargeFiles`, and `LargeStrings` "Binding Configurations".

Now that I have that config, I can also have multiple Behaviors, where one might look like this:

```
<behavior name="DefaultServiceBehavior">
  <serviceCredentials>
    <serviceCertificate findValue="1234123412341234123412341234"
                        x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" />
  </serviceCredentials>
  <serviceMetadata/>
  <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
</behavior>
```

In this case, `DefaultServiceBehavior` is a behavior.

So a different way to ask my question is, ***Why can't my Binding Configuration contain all of my settings that my Behavior specifies? Or vice versa? At a basic and high level, why do we have both sets of settings?*** It seems both can very significantly affect my transport configuration or my message configuration. I just don't see the logic for the separation of settings.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In technical terms:

- [Bindings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733027.aspx): are used to specify the transport, encoding, and protocol details required for clients and services to communicate with each other.
- [Behaviors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480210.aspx): are types that modify or extend Service or Client functionality.

In layman's terms:

- **Bindings**: are used to specify the language your service speaks (ex: English, Portuguese, etc). A service and a client can only communicate with each other if they agree to speak the same language.
- **Behaviours**: are used to define how your service should act. For instance, [British Queen's Guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queen%27s_Guard) are expected to stand perfectly still while on duty, because that's how protocol dictates they should act, otherwise people might doubt they are truly British guards.

Conclusion, your services should speak the appropriate language (binding) and act (behaviour) as they are supposed to otherwise clients might have a hard time trying to communicate with them.

Comment: Thanks! However, by that understanding, I would expect certificate info for transport security to go under bindings and not behaviors. If I speak Pig Latin (encrypted English), the client would need to know about this before we could communicate. No?

Comment: Also, if my example of Pig Latin isn't quite valid, then why does the `<binding>` nodes have a `security` node in there? Seems like that sort of thing either **should** or **should not** be in the binding configuration, not just *sometimes*.

Comment: Using yet another analogy imagine a war in which British soldiers are given an [enigma machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enigma_machine) that allow them to secure their communication against German spies. Then the implicit binding can be regarded as *encrypted English*. German spies are aware of this binding, but they won't be able to understand what British soldiers are saying because only British soldiers have access (behavior) to the enigma machine.

Comment: So, then, would it be fair to say that the binding is just the messenger? Not necessarily somebody who must understand the message, just somebody who must understand how to deliver the message? And if you must actually do something with that message, then you might then need the additional knowledge of the Behavior? That's how you have me thinking of it right now...

Comment: I guess that's fair enough ;) From my point of view a binding configuration simply specifies how messages are transported (like a [transport layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_layer)), whereas behaviours define how messages are interpreted (like an [application layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_layer)).

Comment: Thanks for helping me to understand this. I appreciate it!